# Parsing JSON in Java with variable number of objects

Tags: android, json

My app receives a JSON response from web services and processes the data. The response that is received could have any number of objects. My normal method of parsing is:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray arrChanges = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Changes").getJSONArray("Row");
for (int i = 0; i < arrChanges.length(); i++)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This normally gets the array `Row` inside the object `Changes`, and works fine. However, I tested it with only one record being returned, and suddenly got the error: `JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`. After looking at the json, I can see that because there is now only one object, it is no longer a `JSONArray`, it is now just a `JSONObject`. Meaning that trying to use `getJSONArray` will obviously fail.

So my question is; considering I will receive a varying number of items (0 to lots), how can I reliably parse this data (without knowing how many records it will have)?

Comment: post json response too

Comment: you can check the `length` right?

Comment: You could ask if `jsonObj` is instance of `Array`

Comment: I'll suggest you you use Gson library. Simply create a modal class then you can always check length of array. Or use condition if(jsonObj.getJSONObject("Changes").getJSONArray("Row")!=null) or if(! jsonObj.getJSONObject("Changes").getJSONArray("Row").isEmpty())

Comment: you always know the size of json array so your by this code arrChanges.length(). I think you are using php on your server side and if you json encode empty array it is converted to json array in php

Comment: What? No, I haven't mentioned anything about PHP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing parsing with the help of this concept

```
if (<your jsonobject> instanceof JSONArray)
 {
  //parse as an jsonarray
  for(....;....;...){
 //your logic
 }
 }
 else{
 //parse as jsonobject without using any index value
 }
```

hope this help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Force your json to be an array on the client side.

EDIT: I said client, I just mean wherever you are creating it.

```
var json = [];

json.push({"yourdataname":"yourdatavalue"});
```

Comment: I'd agree that the data should be forced to be an array when the json is created, even if the array only contains one item, you need some structure.

Comment: This is my ideal solution but I'm afraid I don't really understand how this code converts a JSONObject to a JSONArray.

Comment: Your array needs to an array, weather it has 1 item or 1000, not an n sized collection of objects. force it to be like {"Row":[{},{}]}
I hope that helps. I'm not an expert, but I had a similar issue once.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it:

```
try{
JSONArray arrChanges = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Changes").getJSONArray("Row");
for (int i = 0; i < arrChanges.length(); i++)
{
    // do stuff
}
}catch(JSONException e){
//i assume that the actual data is json array if not this block is called try jsonobject parsing here 
// its something like try catch inside try catch
}
```